# Replace every second match in a Excel Cell

Tags: excel, replace

i have a little problem and wonder if i can solve it just by microsoft excel instead of writing a whole script.

I have a csv file with about 11k rows which contain geoposition.

The problem is, latitude and longitude are formatted like this:

lat         lng
51.364.414  19.356.625

Before I upload this data to my database, I'd like to remove the second dot in each of the coordinates.

My question is now, can I somehow apply a formula within the search and replace function of excel? So to say, I want to tell Excel just to replace every second dot in a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming your lat/long values are in two seperate columns;

```
=LEFT(A1,(FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1))-1)&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1))
```

Change the "A1" references to the cell you want to format.

Comment: Why not use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",2)`?